# CSS dynamic vertical align text in <div> that has fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed height `<div>`, as I want all `<div>` elements have the same height. I want to align the text inside the `<div>` to be vertical center dynamically. And is it possible if I don't want to add any tags (`span`, `h1`, etc)?

### CSS

```
.mydiv {
  border-radius: 25px;
  color:#c4c6c7;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
  height: 50px;
  width:40%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#c4c6c7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="mydiv" id="c1" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)">choice 1</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined height on your element the easiest way is to just set `line-height` with same number of `px`

```css
.mydiv {
  border-radius: 25px;
  color:#c4c6c7;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
  height: 50px;
  width:40%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#c4c6c7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="c1" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)">choice 1</div>
```

Other solution is to use `Flexbox` and set `align-items: center` for vertical align

```css
.mydiv {
  border-radius: 25px;
  color:#c4c6c7;
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:white;
  height: 50px;
  width:40%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#c4c6c7;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="c1" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)">choice 1</div>
```

Comment: that's true but should also add "vertical-align: middle" to the trick

Comment: but if the text is longer, then it will move to a lower position

Comment: @androidnewbie if that's a concern then you need to say that in your original question, not when a user has posted the exact answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` to center align the content.

```css
.mydiv {
  border-radius: 25px;
  color:#c4c6c7;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
  height: 150px;
  width:40%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#c4c6c7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="c1" onclick="checkans(this.innerHTML)">choice 1choice 1choice 1choice 1choice 1<br>choice 1choice 1choice 1choice 1choice 1</div>
```

Comment: It also changes the width of my `div`

Comment: can't you use width in `px`?

Answer (score 0):

```
.mydiv {
  border-radius: 25px;
  color:#c4c6c7;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
  height: 50px;
  width:40%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#c4c6c7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center
}
```

And fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/4mu8b9bL/